# Can I use requestAnimationFrame to smooth out scroll behaviour?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a small scroll effect which simulate that a logo will disappear if a lower div will scroll over it.

Currently I'm checking if two divs are intersecting. If this is true, then the height of the div of the logo will decrease with the scroll position of the div beneath.

Unfortunately, my demo is not foolproof and some fragments of the logo are still visible.
Is there a way to do this jank-free? Maybe with requestAnimationFrame?

```js
function elementsOverlap(el1, el2) {
  const domRect1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const domRect2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();

  return !(
    domRect1.top > domRect2.bottom ||
    domRect1.right < domRect2.left ||
    domRect1.bottom < domRect2.top ||
    domRect1.left > domRect2.right
  );
}

const el1 = document.querySelector(".logo");
const el2 = document.querySelector(".clickblocks");

let scrollPositionEl2;
let heightDifference;

const logoHeight = el1.offsetHeight;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var scrollDirectionDown;
  scrollDirectionDown = true;

  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (this.oldScroll > this.scrollY) {
      scrollDirectionDown = false;
    } else {
      scrollDirectionDown = true;
    }
    this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;

    // test
    if (scrollDirectionDown) {
      if (elementsOverlap(el1, el2) === true) {
        scrollPositionEl2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        heightDifference = logoHeight - scrollPositionEl2 + 100;
        //console.log(logoHeight - heightDifference);
        el1.style.height = `${logoHeight - heightDifference}px`;
      }
    } else {
      //scrolling up

      scrollPositionEl2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect().top - 100;
      el1.style.height = `${scrollPositionEl2}px`;
      //console.log(logoHeight);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@900&display=swap");

.wrapper {
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1920/1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 1200px;
  position: relative;

  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    inset: 0;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.clickblocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, (minmax(0, 1fr)));
}

.clickblock {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.2s;
  backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: span 6 / span 6;
  font-size: 54px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 24px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  &:hover {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  }
}

.logo {
  background: url("https://svgshare.com/i/ivR.svg");
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
}

.logo-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <main>
    <div class="logo-wrapper" style="height: 390px">
      <div class="logo" style="height: 300px">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clickblocks">
      <div class="clickblock">
        Some Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Few things here to optimize your performance.

1. `getBoundingClientRect()` is a rather expensive calculation. If there are NO other options it's fine.
2. The [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is a lot more performant, and you can set the `root element` on the API. Then observe the element that is moving. This should be able to telly you if their are colliding.
3. Whenever you do scroll based logic, you should really try and throttle the logic so that the scroll any fires ever 16.6ms.   That will reduce the number of times the calculations are made, and speed things up on the FE.
4. Learn how to use [Google Chrome's performance tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/). It can be overwhelming at first, but it gives you the ability to drill into the exact piece of code that's slowing your site down.
5. Learn about JS's event loop, and what's really going on under the hood. This [video by Jake Archibald](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0) really help me understand it.

---

Hope this helped, sorry that I didn't give you an actual solution.